# maya python: 'list' object is not callable #

Tags: python, maya

so im working on a simple frame counter script as a way to start learning python in maya.

My plan is to have the script figure out how many frames are in the timeline , and then for each frame to create a text number (using the text curves command) then key the visibility on and off of these. I figure this will be faster than building them on the fly. Ive ran into a little problem trying to get the script to build the number on each frame though. 
script below:

***code***

```
import maya.cmds as cmds  
newcurrent = cmds.currentTime(frame)     
start = cmds.playbackOptions( q=True,min=True )
end  = cmds.playbackOptions( q=True,max=True )
timerange = [start, end]

for frame in range (timerange):

        cmds.textCurves( f='Times-Roman', t= newcurrent )
```

its obviously the 'for frame in range (timerange):' section that is causing me some problems. Im not sure on the correct syntax to do what I want here

thanks for any help!

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Comment: 'list' object is not callable # was the full error message from maya

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that `start` and end are `int`s, because you haven't provided that information. (If they're not `int`s, you shouldn't be using `range` anyway.) In the future, aim to create a [mcve].

What you've written amounts to this:

```
range([3, 7])
```

What you want though is this:

```
range(3, 7)
```

You can do this by one of these two approaches:

```
# Option 1
range(*timerange)
# Option 2
range(start, end)
```